# Figuring out the exact key created by PHP's mcrypt

Tags: php, mcrypt, rijndael

A PHP application I'm maintaining uses Rijndael_256 with EBC_MODE encryption with mcrypt. Fun has it that the key isn't 256 bits long, but only 160. According to the [`mcrypt_encrypt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) documentation the key is padded with \0 to get the required size if it's too small.

> The key with which the data will be encrypted. If it's smaller than
>   the required keysize, it is padded with '\0'. It is better not to use
>   ASCII strings for keys.

This seem to happen at around the start of [line 1186 in mcrypt.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.c#L1186) and modifying the key at line 1213.

So lets say we've got `$key = 'abcdefghijkm';` which is too short, but PHP's implementation of mcrypt makes sure it's extended to 32 characters (or 256 bit) when using RIJNDAEL_256. What will the final key look like?

I'm asking this because another application is being built that uses the same encrypted data, but is in another language. Perl to be exact and I'm using [`Crypto::Rijndael`](https://metacpan.org/module/Crypt::Rijndael). For the given example key, what is the exact key I would have to feed to `Crypto::Rijndael` (or any other for that matter) to be able to decrypt the data again?

**Update**

With Perl I can generate a key that's \0 padded doing `pack('a32', 'my secret key');` (or `Z32`), `length()` will report 32 and the `Crypt::Rijndael` module accepts the key. Looking at the source of PHP's mcrypt this should be the key that's being generated (\0 padded), but it simply won't take it.

In theory in PHP `pack('a32', 'my secret key');` should result in the same \0 padded key that PHP's mcrypt generates, but this isn't the case.

I'm very close to just encrypt everything again but with a new key. This is taking too much time.

Comment: Have you tried just padding it with 0s?

Comment: Yes, haven't had any luck with that though.

Comment: Remember that the results might not actually be printable characters, so don't rely on console/page output to determine what the key actually looks like.  But if you write the resulting key out to a binary file, you should be able to pull it into your perl script and use it successfully.

Comment: I'm trying it with plain text that has been encrypted with PHP's `mcrypt_encrypt` and tried to decrypt with Perl's `Crypt::Rijndael`. All I need to know is what the actual key looks like when PHP's `mcrypt_encrypt` is done with it :-).

Comment: Excuse me for not answering the question directly, but I think this is a bad idea. If your key is a password, stretch your value first using a KDF (e.g PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt) and then use the result to encrypt the data.

Comment: Could you explain what KDF stands for? The kind of data that's being encrypted here doesn't matter. The fact is I've got to deal with data that's being encrypted this way and I need to be able to decrypt it using another language, in this case Perl.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue isn't the key's padding, it's that you're using two different block sizes.  In PHP, using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` uses a block size of... 256 bits.  However, in perl using `Crypt::Rijndael`, they note:

> **blocksize**
>   The blocksize for Rijndael is 16 bytes (128 bits), although the algorithm actually supports any blocksize that is any multiple of our bytes. **128 bits, is however, the AES-specified block size, so this is all we support**.

So there's no key that will allow for conversion between those different algorithms.  You can either switch to 128 bits in PHP:

```
<?
$key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$data = "Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument.";
$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, nil);
echo bin2hex($crypttext) . "\n";
// prints c613d1804f52f535cb4740242270b1bcbf85151ce4c874848fd1fc2add06e0cc2d26b6403feef4a8df18f7dd7f8ac67d
?>
```

Which Perl can decrypt without a problem using Crypt::Rijndael:

```
use Crypt::Rijndael;
$key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\0\0\0\0\0\0";
$crypttext = "c613d1804f52f535cb4740242270b1bcbf85151ce4c874848fd1fc2add06e0cc2d26b6403feef4a8df18f7dd7f8ac67d";
$cipher = Crypt::Rijndael->new($key, Crypt::Rijndael::MODE_ECB());
print $cipher->decrypt(pack('H*', $crypttext));
# prints "Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument."
```

Or you can switch to a different Perl module that supports more block sizes, e.g., [Crypt::Rijndael_PP](http://search.cpan.org/~delta/Crypt-Rijndael_PP-0.04/Rijndael_PP.pm):

```
# Same PHP code except using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256
# prints f38469ec9deaadbbf49bb25fd7fc8b76462ebfbcf149a667306c8d1c033232322ee5b83fa87d49e4e927437647dbf7193e6d734242d583157b492347a2b1514c
```

Perl:

```
use Crypt::Rijndael_PP ':all';
$key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\0\0\0\0\0\0";
$crypttext = "f38469ec9deaadbbf49bb25fd7fc8b76462ebfbcf149a667306c8d1c033232322ee5b83fa87d49e4e927437647dbf7193e6d734242d583157b492347a2b1514c";
print rijndael_decrypt(unpack('H*', $key), MODE_ECB, pack('H*', $crypttext), 256, 256);
# prints "Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument."
```

Comment: Thanks, I was already starting to think the blocksize had something to do with it but didn't had the time yet to check it out. I guess I'll be going with `Crypt::Rijndael_PP` then.

Comment: Hmm, whilst `$key` is actually 256bits long `Crypt::Rijndael_PP` still appends 0's to it. Looks to me like there's a bug in it?

Comment: @Htbaa `Crypt::Rijndael_PP` is not as mature a module as `Crypt::Rijndael` and has some oddities.  Notably, it doesn't want the raw key, but the hex string representation.  See my example using it: you have to `unpack` the raw key before passing it in.

Comment: Ah I see, that's indeed a bit strange. Will give it a go.

Answer (score 4):

'\0' means NULL, the hex value of it is 00 !
So i tested 3 codes, and they returned all the same :)

1. Let mcrypt_encrypt do the '\0' padding
2. Added with PHP NULL values
3. Added with PHP converted 0 hex values

Code:

```
function encryptThis($text,$key){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return ($crypttext);
}

echo bin2hex(encryptThis("Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument.", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))."<br/>";

echo bin2hex(encryptThis("Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument.", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" . NULL . NULL . NULL . NULL . NULL . NULL))."<br/>";

echo bin2hex(encryptThis("Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument.", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" . hex2bin(0) . hex2bin(0) . hex2bin(0) . hex2bin(0) . hex2bin(0) . hex2bin(0)))."<br/>";

?>
```

Comment: I'm happy with letting `mcrypt_encrypt` do the \0 padding. I need the exact key so I can use it in another programming language. Thanks for the 0x00 mention, had forgotten about that one. Wonder if perl's `undef` will be the same (doubt it).

Comment: Well it must be 32 characters. In this example the alphabet is 26, 32-26 = 6, so you must add 6 Nulls or 0x00 :)

Comment: The formatting is messed up now. Actually, `$key1` and `$key2` are exactly the same length, so `mcrypt_encrypt` is still taking care of the padding. The same goes for `$key3`. So it's no wonder they give the same result, as to PHP they all containt `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.

Comment: hence the final key is `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" . NULL . NULL . NULL . NULL . NULL . NULL;` ...

Comment: Also `Warning: hex2bin(): Hexadecimal input string must have an even length`. All these 3 examples do exactly the same thing, they let `mcrypt_encrypt` take care of the padding. You're feeding it a key with the length of 26 bytes.

Comment: That warning is because my code is messed up xD ...
Also, i'm not feeding it with a key of 26bytes. 1 NULL = 1 byte, so if you add 6 NULLs to the key it will be 32bytes wich what PHP mcrypt_encrypt exactly do, i'm not a familiar with PERL, but if you add those NULL's it should be the same encryption method :)

Comment: Try doing a `strlen()` on the generated keys. It'll report 26 for all of them, which shouldn't be correct according to what you're saying.

Comment: this is indeed frustrating, '\0' means end of a string, it would be naturaly that strlen() doesn't count that as a string ...

Comment: Since `strlen()` calculates the length of the string in bytes I'd expect it to count a \0 as well, since that's a byte as well. Since we can't be sure yet what PHP does with the string before mcrypt modifies the key string it's still not certain what the string is supposed to end up like.